# Server responded with: 400 while UpdateFile using gdata api

Tags: google-drive-api, gdata

I am using gdata api to update file (updateFile) in google doc. Now things are working for other file type like .pdf, .dwg, .csv etc. But when I try to update file of .txt and .doc files. There is server error response from google.

Server responded with: 400, http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>GData`InvalidEntryException`The conversion cannot be performed since we do not support the input file type.

I dnt know what is the problem. Any one has any idea.

Comment: paste the http request and response

Comment: I am doing a restore of the file from my python file, and as an exception I get this much response only. I am searching for better debugging. Thanks for the response.

Comment: And it too has this message too.Bad Request